# Blocking Operation in Actor NOT Occupying All Default Dispatchers

Tags: scala, akka, actor, blocking, akka-dispatcher

I am learning Akka Actor recently. I read the document of dispatchers in Actor. I am curious about the blocking operation in an actor. The last [topic](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/dispatchers.html#blocking-needs-careful-management) in the document describes how to solve the problem. And I am trying to reproduce the example experiment in the document.

Here is my code:

```
package dispatcher

import akka.actor.{ActorSystem, Props}
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory

object Main extends App{

  var config = ConfigFactory.parseString(
    """
      |my-dispatcher{
      |type = Dispatcher
      |
      |executor = "fork-join-executor"
      |
      |fork-join-executor{
      |fixed-pool-size = 32
      |}
      |throughput = 1
      |}
    """.stripMargin)

//  val system = ActorSystem("block", ConfigFactory.load("/Users/jiexray/IdeaProjects/ActorDemo/application.conf"))


  val system = ActorSystem("block")


  val actor1 = system.actorOf(Props(new BlockingFutureActor()))
  val actor2 = system.actorOf(Props(new PrintActor()))

  for(i <- 1 to 1000){
    actor1 ! i
    actor2 ! i
  }

}

package dispatcher

import akka.actor.Actor

import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, Future}

class BlockingFutureActor extends Actor{
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case i: Int =>
      Thread.sleep(5000)
      implicit val excutionContext: ExecutionContext = context.dispatcher
      Future {
        Thread.sleep(5000)
        println(s"Blocking future finished ${i}")
      }
  }
}
package dispatcher

import akka.actor.Actor

class PrintActor extends Actor{
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case i: Int =>
      println(s"PrintActor: ${i}")
  }
}
```

I simply create an `ActorSystem` with the default dispatchers and all actors depend on those. The `BlockingFutureActor` has a blocking operation that is encapsulated in a `Future`. The `PrintActor` is merely printing a number instantly.

In the document's explanation, the default dispatchers will be occupied by  `Future`s in the `BlockingFutureActor`, which leads to the message blocking of the `PrintActor`. The application gets stuck somewhere like:

```
>　PrintActor: 44
>　PrintActor: 45
```

Unfortunately, my code is not blocked. All outputs from `PrintActor` show up smoothly. But outputs from `BlockingFutureActor` show up like squeezing toothpaste. I try to monitor my thread info by Intellij's Debug, I got:
[image: thread monitoring]

You may find only two dispatchers are sleeping(`BlockingFutureActor` makes this happen). Others are waiting, which means they are available for new message delivering.

I have read an answer about blocking operation in Actor([page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44668898/starvation-of-akka-actors-who-participate-in-a-sequence-process/44671531#44671531)). It is quoted that "Dispatchers are, effectively, thread-pools. Separating the two guarantees that the slow, blocking operations don't starve the other. This approach, in general, is referred to as bulk-heading, because the idea is that if a part of the app fails, the rest remains responsive."

Do default dispatchers spare some dispatcher for blocking operation? Such that the system can handle messages even if there are so many blocking operations asking for dispatchers.

Can the experiment in the Akka document be reproduced? Is there something wrong with my configuration.

Thanks for your suggestions. Best Wishes.

Comment: "All outputs from `PrintActor` show up smoothly." Are you saying that you see all 1000 `println` statements from `PrintActor`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. 1000 `println` show up at the moment that the application starts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you see all 1000 print statements from the `PrintActor` before any print statements from the `BlockingFutureActor` is because of the first `Thread.sleep` call in the `BlockingFutureActor`'s `receive` block. This `Thread.sleep` is the key difference between your code and the example in the official documentation:

```
override def receive: Receive = {
  case i: Int =>
    Thread.sleep(5000) // <----- this call is not in the example in the official docs
    implicit val excutionContext: ExecutionContext = context.dispatcher
    Future {
      ...
    }
}
```

Remember that actors process one message at a time. The `Thread.sleep(5000)` basically simulates a message that takes at least five seconds to process. The `BlockingFutureActor` won't process another message until it's done processing the current message, even if it has hundreds of messages in its mailbox. While the `BlockingFutureActor` is processing that first `Int` message of value `1`, the `PrintActor` has already finished processing all 1000 messages that were sent to it. To make this more clear, let's add a `println` statement:

```
override def receive: Receive = {
  case i: Int =>
    println(s"Entering BlockingFutureActor's receive: $i") // <-----
    Thread.sleep(5000)
    implicit val excutionContext: ExecutionContext = context.dispatcher
    Future {
      ...
    }
}
```

A sample output when we run the program:

```
Entering BlockingFutureActor's receive: 1
PrintActor: 1
PrintActor: 2
PrintActor: 3
...
PrintActor: 1000
Entering BlockingFutureActor's receive: 2
Entering BlockingFutureActor's receive: 3
Blocking future finished 1
...
```

As you can see, by the time the `BlockingFutureActor` actually begins to process the message `2`, the `PrintActor` has already churned through all 1000 messages.

If you remove that first `Thread.sleep`, then you'll see messages dequeued from the `BlockingFutureActor`'s mailbox more quickly, because the work is being "delegated" to a `Future`. Once the `Future` is created, the actor grabs the next message from its mailbox without waiting for the `Future` to complete. Below is a sample output without that first `Thread.sleep` (it won't be exactly the same every time you run it):

```
Entering BlockingFutureActor's receive: 1
PrintActor: 1
PrintActor: 2
...
PrintActor: 84
PrintActor: 85
Entering BlockingFutureActor's receive: 2
Entering BlockingFutureActor's receive: 3
Entering BlockingFutureActor's receive: 4
Entering BlockingFutureActor's receive: 5
PrintActor: 86
PrintActor: 87
...
```

Comment: I feel very sorry for making a stupid bug because of my careless. It is true that `Thread.sleep(5000)` should be encapsulated in a `Future`. And my first `Thread.sleep(5000)` is a stupid bug. I am extremely grateful to you for your patience and help. Best wishes.